# How to avoid mutex_lock from blocking?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I want to use threads with **pthread** in C.

One question I have about threads is why mutex lock does not block the execution when the whole application relays on one shared ressource?

Bodo

Comment: You are probably using it incorrectly. Care to show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `pthread_mutex_trylock()` function.

> The   pthread_mutex_trylock()   function   shall   be   equivalent to
>   pthread_mutex_lock(), except that if the  mutex  object  referenced  by
>   mutex  is  currently  locked  (by  any  thread,  including  the current
>   thread), the call shall  return  immediately.

Reference: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_mutex_trylock.txt

Comment: One should think at least twice whether `pthread_mutex_trylock()` is really the solution, if running into a dead-lock.